# I can't use $_SESSION and the script freezes after session_start()

Tags: php, mysql, web, session, server

I'm calling a php script with a fetch request.

```
fetch("../php_modules/userWork/addContact.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(user.textContent)
})
```

php file

```
require_once "../connection.php";
    session_start();
    $newContact = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

 $currentUser=$db->query("
    SELECT ID, CONTACTS_LIST
    FROM users 
    WHERE EMAIL = '".$_SESSION['email']."'
 ");
```

The code is not complete, but there is nothing important there. What happens:
After running the script, I turn on session_start() and try to take a parameter from $_SESSION. But nothing works. I can't output messages either. But when I set an arbitrary value instead of $_SESSION['email'], everything works, but again without messages. What is the problem and how to fix it?

The request status is set to 200;

Comment: `$_SESSION['email']` was probably not set the first time you call your PHP. Also you miss the comma `'` like `WHERE EMAIL = '".$_SESSION['email']."'`

Comment: You're missing quotes around the email address. You should use prepared statements so that you're not bitten by that, or the inevitable SQL injection.

Comment: Where is `$_SESSION['email']` defined?

Comment: I added parentheses and checked for the presence of 'email'. Everything is there, but the code does not work

Comment: I checked that in all the files that I call through fetch and call the session there is such a problem

Comment: Answer!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218166/php-session-issue-with-javascript-fetch